# 'Add Field' option is not showing up in the attribute table 'Option' in ArcGIS Online map Viewer

Tags: arcgis-online

I am trying to add a new field in the attribute table in ArcGIS Online map viewer but for some reason, the option to add field is not showing up. I am using a Cache service and a dynamic service. I can't figure out what could be the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add, delete, and calculate fields on **hosted feature layers**. Cached services or dynamic map services wont work http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/work-with-fields.htm#GUID-BE260302-CEA6-4A3A-8933-60911375943A